# Acumatica - Calculate overdue charges based on custom payment plan

Tags: c#, finance, acumatica

I'm trying to figure out how to modify the business logic code used to calculate overdue charges on an invoice. I have a grid in the credit terms page that has a payment plan showing that for every 30 days, a customer has to pay 10% of the original balance. So if somebody bought something worth $100, after 30 days they would owe $10, after 60 they would owe another $10, etc. I need to figure out some way that the overdue charge takes this into account. So ideally, it would work like this:

```
read in payment plan info
calculate amount paid on invoice
determine if amount paid on invoice is amount that should have been paid up to current date
if payments are up to date, don't add overdue charge
else, determine how many days late the customer is, and calculate overdue charge based on overdue rate and number of late days
```

Continuing on the previous example, let's say we calculate the overdue charges on day 72 after the original purchase. If the customer has only paid the first installment and hasn't paid the 60 day installment, the overdue charge of 12 days would be added on top of the $10 they haven't yet paid.

Is any of this functionality already in Acumatica or would all of this need to be custom? I've only taken the T100 and T200 development courses, so I don't know if this is built in. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you configure multiple installments in credit terms then invoice with this credit terms will be closed on release and a batch of invoices with different due dates will be generated. 
For instance you have credit terms with settings like that: 
[image]

You create invoice with amount 100$ and release it.
10 invoices for 10$ will be generated with different due dates.
Overdue charges works fine with these invoices. So needed functionality is built in.

Comment: Is it possible to only create one invoice instead of multiple?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.